# Short circuiting not working in react render div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-component

I want to start multiple components when a variable is true and I am using as follow:

```
return (
        <div className="report">
            {conditionalVariable &&
            <ComponentA/> &&
            <ComponentB/>
            }
         </div>
    )
```

However, when the variable is true, only component A is getting up but not component B.What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you're getting any output. Those conditional components once you've worked out the logic, need to have a parent - either with a fragment, or a div, or something.

You would have seen something similar to this error:

> SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

```js
const { Fragment, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ conditional, setConditional ] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setConditional(!conditional);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {conditional && (
        <Fragment>
          <Test text="Bob" />
          <Test text="Sue" />
        </Fragment>
      )}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

function Test({ text }) {
  return <p>{text}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I am adding these in existing code.I cannot keep them in child div as it is disturbing the layout.See my comment in above answer.I am able to run them separately.But if i want to combine them without using child div.Is it possible

Comment: [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). I updated my answer.

Comment: < Fragment > worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are set rather strange. Try it like this:

```
return (
    <div className="report">
        {conditionalVariable &&
            <>
                <ComponentA />
                <ComponentB />
            </>
        }
    </div>
)
```

This solution uses the short syntax of [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) to group the two components you want to display under the same condition.

Comment: updated curly braces in question.but there is error with your syntax, Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token.(It is coming at <>)

Comment: Have you imported React?

Comment: its the code works fine if I use {conditionalVariable && <ComponentA/>} and then {conditionalVariable && <ComponentB/>}. I was wondering If i can keep them at place instead of two(one after another)

Comment: I don't see any real difference there. You want to have both components rendered in this order - under the same condition. That is what the code does.

Comment: if I use div in the empty angular brackets, <div>
                <ComponentA />
                <ComponentB />
            </div>, then it works fine, but div disturbs layout

Comment: That's exactly what fragments are used for. To give elements a common parent node without adding additional elements (e.g. `<div>`) to the DOM. See if you can get this to work. Have you checked the imports?

Comment: < Fragment > worked fine but i have to write Fragment keyword as mentioned in another answer